# Get number of modules of a running process

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to get total number of modules of a running process by passing process ID
This is function that return total number of modules in a process

```
int size(DWORD processID)
{
HMODULE hMods[1024];
HANDLE hProcess;
DWORD cbNeeded;
// Print the process identifier.
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
PROCESS_VM_READ,
FALSE, processID);
// Get a list of all the modules in this process.

EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded);
int j = (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE));

return j;


// Release the handle to the process.

}
```

this is main

```
int main()
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024];
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    DWORD cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    // Get the list of process identifiers.
    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
        return 1;

    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the names of the modules for each process.

    for (int i = 0; i <= cProcesses; i++) {
        int a = size(aProcesses[1]);
        //std::string* g = PrintModules(aProcesses[1], a);
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile & run this code output is 855987977 etc 
I tried multiple ways but all in vain...

Comment: Did you check the value returned by `EnumProcessModules`? How do you know it did not fail?

Comment: when I debug it function return negative value but in output something different

Comment: If I run this in a function that return module name then it works properly but if I seprate these lines then it does not work

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in `i <= cProcesses`. Must be `i < cProcesses`. And why do you refer to `aProcesses[1]` in the loop? Shouldn't it be `aProcesses[i]`?

Comment: `int PrintModules(DWORD processID)
{HMODULE hMods[1024];HANDLE hProcess;DWORD cbNeeded;unsigned int i; printf("\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID);
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE, processID);if (NULL == hProcess)return 1;
if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded)){
long j = (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE));
cout << j;for (i = 0; i < j; i++){TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess,hMods[i], szModName,sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR))){_tprintf(TEXT(szModName, hMods[i]);
}}}CloseHandle(hProcess);return 0;}`

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't catch it.Thank u so much for pointing it out

Comment: @john don't put code like that in a comment.  Edit your question, or post an answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard method of EnumprocessModules, the output argument is the size in bytes of the array:

`lpcbNeeded = The number of bytes required to store all module handles in the lphModule array.`

Divide it by the size of the element type (HMODULE) and that will yield the number of modules.

```cpp
int GetNumberOfModules(DWORD processID)
{
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    HANDLE hProcess;
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    unsigned int i;

    // Print the process identifier.

    printf("\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID);

    // Get a handle to the process.

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
        PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE, processID);
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return 1;

    // Get a list of all the modules in this process.

    if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
    {
        //return number of modules by dividing size of array by element size
        return cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE);
    }

    // Release the handle to the process.

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```